# PyCharm Interpreter configuration error, code example with Neo4j with Python Driver

Tags: python, neo4j, pycharm

I started a local neo4j server and work with it using Python (PyCharm)

Installed with (`python -m pip install --upgrade neo4j==4.0.0`)

**Python 3.8**

**Neo4j 4.0**

```py
from neo4j import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("neo4j://localhost:7687", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "12345"))
session = driver.session()
session.run("CREATE (a:Person {name:'Bob'})")
result = session.run("MATCH (a:Person) RETURN a.name AS name")

for record in result:
    print(record["name"])

session.close()
driver.close()
```

But when the program starts, it returns an error. What to do?

```
D:\PyCharm\projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe add -i D:\PyCharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=52885
D:\Python\python.exe: can't open file 'add': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Process finished with exit code 2
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you run the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have wrong PyCharm Interpreter configuration and/or Run Configuration.

Try running code with console command from Terminal, not from PyCharm.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I changed settings, and everything worked!

Comment: if anybody wants to change interpreter -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter